# serialPort communicatin with thread ,in monodevelop IDE ,using C#

Tags: c#, thread-safety, serial-port, monodevelop

my steps:
1.using System.IO.Ports;using system.Threading;

2.SerialPort mySerialPort=new SerialPort("Com1",9200,Parity.None,8,StopBits.One);
**3.mySerialPort.Open();**     //*Exception Caught:System.IO.IOException has been thrown :has no such file or directory.*

4.myThread=new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ReadPortThread));
5.myThread.Start(mySerialPort);

6.ReadPortThread(SerialPort serialPort()   //receiving the data from serialport.

Hope you give some suggestion to the problem.

Comment: maybe Com1 needs to be COM1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'am also working on a serialPort communication, and mine works:

```
            ///<summary>
            ///creating new serialPort, fill it with a portname and give it BaudRate value 9600.
            ///</summary>
            _serialPort = new SerialPort();
            _serialPort.PortName = portname;
            _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;

            try
            {
                if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    //open the port.
                    _serialPort.Open();
                }
                //when the port is open
                if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
                {          
                    _serialUsbThread = new Thread(SerialWorker);
                    _serialUsbThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
                    _serialUsbThread.Start();
                }   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow + " SERIAL: " + ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks .your code really help me.Beacuse I am in Ubuntu system which is a Linux system,I should set the portname as "/dev/ttyS0",not "COM1".I use this serial port: "/dev/ttyS0".

Comment: Select it as an answer then:)